# HTC One - keeps shutting down when rooting

Tags: rooting, root-access, htc, htc-one, shutdown

Im rooting my phone (HTC One Alps) via Kingo Android Root. When i connect my phone to the computer and start rooting then phone shutdown itself.

Is there any partition or disk problem?

Comment: "start rooting": what's the exact step when the phone turns itself off? Is it as soon as you plug it in? Or is it triggered by some step in the procedure you're following?

Comment: shutdown himself when rooting by kingo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If reboot:**
This is just part of the process of rooting on some devices and some devices it won't do this.

**If shut down:**
It means the root is installed on your phone and the rooting process is finished.

Hope this helps